Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a+6bc}{a+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+6ac}{b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+6ab}{c+6}}\ge 3.$
I found the inequality here (#25) :
Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$
Prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+6bc}{a+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+6ac}{b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+6ab}{c+6}}\ge 3$$
I have checked that it's true and there are 3 equality cases: $a=b=c$  , $(0,2,2)$ and $a=b\to 0^+$. This makes the problem harder because I don't know how to apply any inequality to save equality cases. Holder skills like Bacteria, CYH cannot solve it.
I also think that there can be a lemma such that River Li's lemma to cancel the root. I've tried to choose a suitable constant $M$ such that if $x,y,z$ be nonnegative and
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+M\cdot x^2y^2z^2 \ge 3+M.$$
then we get $x+y+z \ge 3.$ But it doesn't work because there's just two equality cases.
So I then tried
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+M\cdot (x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) +K\cdot x^2y^2z^2 \ge 3+3M+K.$$
but I still got stuck here.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you.
Edit: I find $M=\dfrac{8}{9},K=\dfrac{10}{3}$, and the lemma is true.
Can I apply this lemma to cancel to root?
